# How to perform XML style checking?

Tags: build, checkstyle, xml-formatting

Unformatted XML is a problem in our build. I would like to include style checking for XML documents, primarily looking for poor indentation.

What is the best tool to use? (The build uses Ant).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a class that will automatically transform and therefore indent your XML. Then just specify in Ant on which XML files it should be ran.

Something to get you started:

```
String filePath = "test.xml";
String outputFilePath = "testOut.xml";

File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
File outputXmlFile = new File(outputFilePath);

Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "3");

StreamSource ss = new StreamSource(xmlFile);
StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(outputXmlFile);      

transformer.transform(ss, sr);
```

Comment: Thanks +1 - however, I want to check the formatting, rather than reformat. Granted, I could use the same approach (write something to check diff formatted == original), but I was looking for something that already exists - such as a method of using checkstyle for xml or somesuch.

Answer (score 0):

Check XCOP: http://www.yegor256.com/2017/08/29/xcop.html

This is how you integrate it with ant:

```
<project>
  <target name="xcop">
    <apply executable="xcop" failonerror="true">
      <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="**/*.xml"/>
        <include name="**/*.xsd"/>
        <exclude name="target/**/*"/>
        <exclude name=".idea/**/*"/>
      </fileset>
    </apply>
  </target>
</project>
```